# How to make CSS Transform: Scale perform more like Zoom

Tags: css, zooming, transform

I have a website that has a "popup" panel that allows you to pick a html template. They are shown smaller at this stage to make the user experience better.

This is my selector.

> ```
>     .panel-overlay .panel-inner .section-preview
>     {
>         display: block;
>         width: 100%;
>         margin-bottom: 50px;
>         border: 1px solid black;
>         cursor: pointer;
>         zoom: 0.2;
>     }
> ```

Using the deprecated "Zoom: 0.2;" attribute it looks exactly right

[image]

However I can't use this because on the iPad it doesn't scale the templates at all, the attribute isn't supported by IOS, so I took advice to use "Transform: scale(0.9) and it looks terrible on all devices.

I can't seem to find a way to make this look more like the Zoom property did, do you know how I can?

[image: This is what the transform: scale option looks like]

Answer (score 0):

Are you applying the transform to just the parent element?

transform on parents and children..

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/bz6eLwr3/1/

**VS**

transform on just the parent

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/bz6eLwr3/3/

**required html code for fiddles**

```
.zoom {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Comment: I have tried applying it to both, it seems to be great until you actually have content inside the divs. When you apply transform: scale to anything it gets a mind of its own and centres itself vertically with no styles hinting at why. It also appears to not be able to judge how large the content inside it is when scaled. I have tried to recreate my example in jsFiddle, but its far to complex - too much markup, images and styles to make it function remotely close.

Comment: I can imagine, there's a lot of imperfect behavior with transforms that need different corrections on each browser. My only advice is to rewrite it to be responsive, if it isn't already, and avoid `transform: scale`.